# Go: vim autocomplete <ENTER> command don't works

Tags: go, vim, editor, coc.nvim, vim-go

autocomplete in vim doesn't work when I hit ENTER and the cursor go to the next line.

this is my .vimrc configuration: https://github.com/marcosvidolin/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Popup example:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add this to your .vimrc

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <cr> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<C-g>u\<CR>"
```

source : [Completion with sources](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Completion-with-sources#use-cr-to-confirm-completion)

Answer (score 1):

I am using vim and using Coc module for language server configuration.
Try to run these following steps:

- Install gopls `GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest`
- Open you vim and type `:CocConfig` and setting up go language configuration like the following bellow. (note: feel free to customize the value, especially in field rootPatterns)

```
{
    "languageserver": {
        "golang": {
            "command": "gopls",
            "rootPatterns": ["go.mod", "main.go", ".vim/", ".git/", ".hg/"],
            "filetypes": ["go"],
            "initializationOptions": {
                "usePlaceholders": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- Save File and Reload your vim configuration